# Javascript clicked and not been clicked for 4 seconds

Tags: javascript, if-statement, click, setinterval

I have a question about my code. What I'm trying to do is if a certain button is clicked and it isn't clicked again within 4 seconds, a element will be showed and another element hide. But if it is clicked within 4 seconds, it stays the same and so on. I think I should use SetInterval() and ClearInterval(). Currently I have two other functions that do other things. Maybe I can my function there?

Hopefully I have made it clear.

Current javascript code:

```
var clicks = 0;
function clicks5times() {
  clicks = clicks+1;
  if(clicks == 6){
    document.getElementById('scherm3').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('scherm2.2').style.display = 'none'; 
  }
}           

var clicked = false;
setInterval(function(){
    if (!clicked) {
    document.getElementById("scherm4").style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById("scherm2.2").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
},13000);

document.getElementById("buttontimer").addEventListener("click", function(){
    clicked = true;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than set interval, I would say a timer would be better. Eg:

```
var clickTimer;

function startTimer() {
  clickTimer = window.setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("scherm4").style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("scherm2.2").style.visibility = "hidden";
  },4000);
}

function stopTimer() {
   window.clearTimeout(clickTimer);
}

function restartTimer() {
   stopTimer();
   startTimer();
}

document.getElementById("buttontimer").addEventListener("click", function(){
    restartTimer();
});
```

This way when you want to stop the timer or start the timer, you have to just call above functions for other scenarios.

eg:

If you have an init function:

```
function init() {
 ...
 //some code
 startTimer();
}
```

And maybe call stop timer like so:

```
function clicks5times() {
  ...
  stopTimer();
}
```

Comment: timer is better approach in this case, +1,.

Comment: The timer starting works, but the 'stop' function doesn't work. How should I implement this in my HTML?

Comment: If you want it to stop, call the clearTimer function, and it should stop.

Comment: I have renamed my function, if that makes more sense. The important part is that the clickTimer variable should be shared between all the other functions.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar what do you mean by shared between all the other functions? and where should I call the stopTimer, just like this: stoptimer();?

Comment: I have updated the answer. But the functions should all be in the same file and at the same level for this to work. That is what I mean by shared. eg: The variable should not be inside one function, or class, and called in another.

Comment: I got it! Question: How can I make sure that the timer doesn't repeats every time I click on it? I really looking for: 
1 click = start
2 click = stop
3 click = start
4 click = stop and so on

Comment: use another flag, called triggerTimer, initialised to true, check for it inside the click handler, and if true call restart, if false call stop, and at the end set triggerTimer = !triggerTimer

Comment: @annaneedshelp Please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

in Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="buttontimer">fghfgh</button>

</body>
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="buttontimer">fghfgh</button>
<script>

document.getElementById('buttontimer').onclick = function(){
document.getElementById("buttontimer").disabled=true;
setInterval(function(){
    if (document.getElementById("buttontimer").disabled == true) {
     document.getElementById("buttontimer").disabled = false;
  }
},10000);

};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and Jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var button = $('<button>Click Me</button>');

    button.clicked = false;

    $('body').append(button);
    var clicked  = false;

    button.click(function(){


      button.clicked = true;
      button.prop('disabled', true);
    clicked = true
    setInterval(function(){
        if (clicked) {
         button.prop('disabled', false);
      }
    },10000);

    });


    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

once u click button disable the property after the timer finish enable back the property

Comment: common just remove the ready and click make to script thats is this need to explain , check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Split your event handlers in two different functions (eg `firstClick` and `secondClick`). The first handler should just add a second event listener and remove it after 4 seconds. For this one-off task, use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` as you need the task to be done only once after 4 seconds and not every 4 seconds. So I would proceed as follows:

```
var secondClick = function() {
     // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO HAPPEN AFTER THE SECOND CLICK
}

var firstClick = function() {

 // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO HAPPEN AFTER THE FIRST CLICK

 document.getElementById("buttontimer").addEventListener("click", secondClick);
 setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("buttontimer").removeEventListener("click", secondClick);
    }, 4000);
};

buttonElement.addEventListener("click", firstClick);
```